# Which API to use to load an Image template

Tags: api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I have created Image templates(actions > create image template) from softlayer UI. I want to load that Image template from API. Which API should I use ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Virtual servers and bare metal servers provides the method reload:

http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/reloadOperatingSystem
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Hardware_Server/reloadOperatingSystem

in the reload you just need to send the image template id, see this example using the Python client:

https://softlayer.github.io/python/reload_hardware/

Regards